# What is the effect of put call open Interest on price action

Tags: options, american-options, put-call-parity, binary-options, put-call-duality

how option put call open Interest affects price actions as put sellers feel price when price goes down or call sellers feel pain when price goes up and how this affects price action. ie when price goes up and call Sellers feel pain they need to buy stock to cover their naked sell call further driving up price and put sellers see price going down need to close out their position. And how put open interest acts as support and call open interest acts as resistance. Is there an Indicator that show how much call open interest is buying VS selling calls
And how much of put oi is buying VS selling puts as this will affect price action differently

Comment: This Q&A might help you a little: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33327/call-vs-put-open-interest/33340#33340